# Azure CDN Standard Akamai Profile

Tags: http2, akamai, azure-cdn

To get the benefit of HTTP/2, I have created a new Akamai standard profile in Azure CDN and linked it with one of our endpoint [origin type as storage]. 
But, if we compare new cdn profile [ Akamai Standard ] with old cdn profile [ Standard Verizon ], old cdn profile's images loads faster.
I'm not sure HTTP/2 is applied or not to new cdn profile [ Akamai Standard ].
Is any check points where we can check HTTP/2 is properly set or not?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has a [HTTP/2 and SPDY indicator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http2-and-spdy-indicator/mpbpobfflnpcgagjijhmgnchggcjblin?hl=en) which you could use in order to tell if the web server is serving http/2 or not. Firefox has [a similar extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/spdy-indicator/).